# jade error agent a1 died without being properly terminated. error state 2

Tags: java, agents-jade

i am new to jade , i want to setup a auctioneer agent that give time and count of items and then ... but i get this error

- jade error agent a1 died without being properly terminated. error
  state 2
  my codes:

  int timeout=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What's Running time of Auction in sec?"));

  ```
        number=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What's the number of items?"));

        //service registration
        DFAgentDescription dfd = new DFAgentDescription();
        dfd.setName(getAID());
        ServiceDescription sd = new ServiceDescription();
        sd.setType("Uniform-Price-Auction");
        sd.setName("Uniform-Price-Auction");
        dfd.addServices(sd);
        try {
            DFService.register(this, dfd);
        }
        catch (FIPAException fe) {
            fe.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Add the behaviour serving queries from buyer agents
        addBehaviour(new getBids());

        // Add the behaviour serving purchase orders from buyer agents
        addBehaviour(new DetermineWinner(this,timeout*1000));


        gui=new ActioneerGUI();
        gui.setVisible(true);
        gui.setlabel1("We want to sell "+number+" items");
        gui.setlabel2("Auction is running...");
  ```

Comment: is this code a code of a behavior? As far as I know, this error raise when  an error occurs during execution of behaviors. Try to wrap all your code in try-catch block to find the error or look through the concole. Are there any stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

Consider that a JADE Agent is a Java Thread in the end and wherever an error occurs, it will cause that the agent or thread will be terminated (regulary this happens in the AgentWrapper class, if I'm correct).

Also keep in mind that with a call to a JOptionPane (which is Swing), you affect two threads: the agents thread and the Swing thread that possibly causes concurrency problems. Better do not mix them up; instead use the O2A interface of the agent by separating the end user application / visualization from an agent.